# GCP Quota for Multiple Spot/Preemptible GPUs into a Single Region is Always Denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, gpu

I am trying to build deep neural network models natural for language processing models like GPT2 or BERT.

The request for GPUS_ALL_REGIONS is partially approved for 4 GPUs, I want to use multiple GPUs (at most 4) in a single instance.

However, all requests which assign more than 2 PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_{A100 or V100}_GPUS (i.e. spot or preemptible) into a single region are denied.

*How could I obtain quote for multiple spot GPUs in a single region?*

**What I did so far:**

- Checked billing account and credit card is correctly registered.
- Confirmed not to log-in as a free trial user.
- Repeated to send Quota Request many times for various regions and various GPU types(A100, V100, T4, P100)
- Confirmed to log-in `gcloud auth log-in` as the account of 1.

**As a result, I expect:**

- The number of GPUs “1” is increased into 4 for each single region.
- GPUS_ALL_REGIONS is increased into 4 times of the number of regions.
- The following gcloud-cli would be successfully executed with ACCELERATOR=="count="${NUM_GPUS}",type=nvidia-tesla-a100"

```bash
gcloud compute instances create ${VM_NAME} --preemptible \
    --zone ${ZONE} \
    --machine-type ${MACHINE_TYPE} \
    --network-interface=${NETWORK_INTERFACE} \
    --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
    --provisioning-model=SPOT \
    --service-account="**********@developer.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --accelerator=${ACCELERATOR} \
    --enable-display-device --tags=http-server,https-server \
    --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=instance-1,image=projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-11-bullseye-v20221206,mode=rw,size=${BOOT_DISK_SIZE},type=projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/zones/${ZONE}/diskTypes/${BOOT_DISK_TYPE} \
    --image-project ${IMAGE_PROJECT} \
    --image-family ${IMAGE_FAMILY} \
    --no-shielded-secure-boot --shielded-vtpm --shielded-integrity-monitoring --reservation-affinity=any \
    --threads-per-core=2 --visible-core-count=6 \
```

Comment: I also have this problem. The e-mails from Google don't mention any reason whatsoever and it is quite frustrating, I must say. The non-spot instances work fine.